# select content of div with DOM, but without child

Tags: javascript, html, dom

there is HTML code:

```
<div id="parent">
    <p>111111</p>
    <div id="child">
        <p>22222</p>
        <div id="childer">
            <p>33333</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want only select "22222" in paragraph of div with id=child.

but when use `document.getElementById("child").textContent` it return "22222" and "33333".
i dont want use jQuery, can anyone help me?
thanks

Comment: Have a look at `.querySelector()` or `.children` or `.getElementsByTagName()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `querySelector()`, more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

> The `Document` method **querySelector()** returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```js
var value = document.querySelector('#child p').textContent;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <p>111111</p>
    <div id="child">
        <p>22222</p>
        <div id="childer">
            <p>33333</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [**`querySelector()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which allows CSS like selector (`#child p`):

```js
var elText = document.querySelector("#child p").textContent;
console.log(elText);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <p>111111</p>
    <div id="child">
        <p>22222</p>
        <div id="childer">
            <p>33333</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const setup = () => {
 const child = document.querySelector('#child');
  const p = child.querySelector('p');
  console.log(p.textContent);
};

//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <p>111111</p>
      <div id="child">
        <p>22222</p>
        <div id="childer">
          <p>33333</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("child").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerText;
```